# How to know which application is the responsible from my windows error?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-error-reporting, unwanted-application

I receive this error:

```
ServiceHub.Helper.exe - Application Error
The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occurred in the application at location 0x0007FFB84F2051C
```

I think one of my applications is crashing. How can I know which application is responsible for this error?

I have event logger turned on.

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0):

An internet search says `ServiceHub.Helper.exe` probably belongs to Cold Turkey website blocker. Here is someone getting the same error message from that application (for unknown reasons):

[image: screenshot]

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/mr866s/computer_crashes_when_using_microsoft_remote/

---

You may be able to just search your machine for `ServiceHub.Helper.exe` (or cold turkey) to find where it's installed at.